# Unwanted spacing between text and tikzpicture caused by "non-visual" code lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, directlua

I want to show some subgraphs of a certain graph. I want them side by side and labeled.
This is what I've got:
[image]

I can't provide working LaTeX-code, since I have implemented the graphdrawing functionality in Lua, but here is what it looks like:

```
\def\coords{(0,0), (1,0), (1, 1), (0,1)}
\def\edges{1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 4/1, 2/4}
\def \scale {0.8}
\def \pos {center}
\begin{center}
     \scalebox{\scale}{(1)\xgraph{\coords}{\edges}{2/3, 3/4}{\pos}} 
     \scalebox{\scale}{(2)\xgraph{\coords}{\edges}{1/2, 4/1}{\pos}}
     \scalebox{\scale}{(3)\xgraph{\coords}{\edges}{}{\pos}}
\end{center}
```

The xgraph macro is:

```
\directlua{gd = require("lua/graphdrawing")}
\newcommand{\xgraph}[5][]{
    \begingroup
    \edef\vertexcoords{#2}
    \edef\edges{#3}
    \edef\blankedges{#4}
    \def\positioning{#5}
    %
    \directlua{
        v, e = gd.get_graph_objects("\vertexcoords", "\edges", "\blankedges")
        vertex_data = gd.tikzify(v)
        edge_data = gd.tikzify(e)}
    \edef\vertexdata{\directlua{tex.print(vertex_data)}}
    \edef\edgedata{\directlua{tex.print(edge_data)}}
    %
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.5, nodes={circle,draw}, baseline=(current bounding box.\positioning)]
        \foreach \x/\y/\style [count=\i] in \vertexdata {
            \node[\style] (\i) at (\x, \y) {\i};
        }
        \foreach \i/\j/\style in \edgedata {
            \draw[\style] (\i)--(\j);
        }
        \draw [red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \endgroup
}
```

As you can see from the picture, there is unwanted spacing between the labels and the TikZ pictures, in such a way that the labels seem to pair up with the wrong pictures. Note that I have added the bounding boxes of the TikZ pictures, so that is not what causes the problem.
Eventually I figured out that the problem is the LaTeX-code that comes in the beginning of the xgraph macro, but before the TikZ-picture environment. When I placed this code inside the TikZ figure (quite unnatural in my opinion), the issue was resolved.

My question is: how can LaTeX code which is not supposed to generate output (variable definitions, \directlua blocks), cause spaces in the document? What is the best way to resolve it? Having everything in the TikZ figure seems inelegant, is this really the standard way of doing it?

Comment: A note: use `\newcommand` rather than `\def` as with the latter you might overwrite already existing macros, since you're using common terms. To avoid this you can also make them more unique, like adding `my` so that it says `myscale` for example.

Comment: For the whitespace, have you tried to remove `scalebox`? I can't help but think that there isn't actually whitespace, so the numbers are correctly placed, but when you scale down the graphs, it... well, makes them smaller so they get far away from the number. I might be terribly wrong though, and I can't test it on my own at the moment.

Comment: @Alenanno Thanks for the suggestion. I have tested it, and `scalebox` doesn't make a difference. I think I have verified that the problem is caused by the code in front of the TikZ environment. I'm asking because this doesn't make sense to me - and is it a good solution to have everything in the TikZ environment, which seems like the only solution?

Comment: Ah ok, I wasn't really sure but it was worth a try. Have you tried the basic troubleshooting against whitespace? I.e. add `%`, for example in front of open brackets, or before new lines, like `\newcommand{\xgraph}[5][]{% <--- here` and so on.

Comment: @Alenanno I generally agree, but the code block in the example (drawing subgraphs) is something that comes up all the time in my document, and in fact, I use these names every time (thus I have to use `def`). It is tedious to come up with new names all the time.

Comment: @Alenanno Thanks again, I just tried to remove every possible whitespace, like you said. I also removed indentation. It didn't work. But are you saying that the spaces shouldn't normally occur by just having definitions etc? For now I will just put all code inside the TikZ environment, but it doesn't feel right somehow.

Comment: Not sure I understand your last question. Well, not sure what is causing that space, as I'd like to test on my own machine, but one of the most common causes is trailing spaces which you remove by adding `%`. Other causes are commands that interfere with each other, and that's why I was looking at `\scalebox`. I have never used Lualatex, but tomorrow I might try to see if I can do something. Unless someone comes along and solves it for you. :D I have added some tags to your question.

Comment: @Alenanno Well, thanks a lot, anyways. And while I do have a working solution, it was just very weird to me how "non-visual" code creates spacing between elements, so I had to ask about it.

Comment: And if you want to test the code, you need both LuaLatex and an external Lua file (module) that I created. I could send it to you, however I don't really think it's the Lua backend that causes this.

Comment: Remove all the spurious spaces (the end of lines) in the xgraph definition by hiding them with a %.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Seems like this is the solution after all. I even need the %'s after the lines inside the Lua-block, which is a bit surprising to me. Of course I should have checked this properly when Alenanno suggested it. I thought it was enough to check that there is no whitespace, I wasn't aware of the importance of the %-signs. Thanks to both of you.